# R plotly scatter marker plot distance ticks and axes

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

How come the distance between the ticks and axes is so huge? Moreover why doenst this chart start at 0?

```
library(plotly)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y = c(0, 10, 14, 18, 24, 30)
)

# Create a scatter plot with markers
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
               marker = list(size = 10, color = 'blue'), 
               text = ~paste('Point ', seq_along(x)))

# Show the plot
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change this with the `layout()` function:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
               marker = list(size = 10, color = 'blue'), 
               text = ~paste('Point ', seq_along(x))) %>%
  layout(
  xaxis = list(range = c(0, max(df$x))),
  yaxis = list(range = c(0, max(df$y))),
  margin = list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 10, t = 10, pad = 4)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to merge the 0?

Comment: Set the tick values excluding 0: `plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 10, color = 'blue'), 
        text = ~paste('Point ', seq_along(x))) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(range = c(0, max(df$x))),
    yaxis = list(
      range = c(0, max(df$y)),
      tickvals = setdiff(pretty(range(df$y)), 0)  
    ),
    margin = list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 10, t = 10, pad = 4)
  )`

Comment: Thx! Alright last question: how do set the y-axis correct when I have 2 differnt y-datasets and still keep reactivity? If I set the y-axis limit to the max of dataset1..and I disable it in the legend, the y-axis doesnt resize to datset 2. Which is annoying if dataset 2 has much smaller values

Comment: found it...add yaxis = list(rangemode = 'tozero')